# how to get 3dmodesl(dae,obj,etc) as a layer from geoserver

Tags: webgl, geoserver, cesiumjs, 3d-model

Is it possible for Geoserver to give  set of 3D models like .dae, .obj, etc, in a KML format. I would store the 3dmodels in geoserver, only link will be generated for front-end developers.

Answer (score 2):

The KMZ format is a ZIP-compressed version of KML, that can contain `*.dae` (which is a COLLADA 3D model) along with the model's texturemaps.

I can't speak to Geoserver's capabilities, perhaps a Geoserver expert will chime in here on how to serve custom files like this.

But since you tagged this question with Cesium, I should note that a Cesium client isn't going to ingest the COLLADA format natively, as COLLADA and indeed KMZ are not good delivery formats to target web browsers (at least not without the now-retired Google Earth plugin).

Cesium natively loads models from the [glTF format](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF), published by [Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/gltf), the makers of COLLADA.  As such there are some [COLLADA to glTF converters](https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html) available.  These glTF models then can be embedded in or referenced from [CZML](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer), which is Cesium's preferred delivery format.